# Button's onclick works but JS event listener does not

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener, mouseclick-event

I have the following button:

```
<input type="button" class ="anhalteButton" id="StopButton" value="&#9611 &#9611"/>
```

which I want to execute the following function (viewsLoop is a global variable):

```
function clearTDLoop(){ 

    clearInterval(viewsLoop);
}
```

If I call the function via the button's `onclick` attribute. i.e.:
`onclick="clearTDLoop()"` it works flawlessly.

However, I would like to call the function through a JS event listener, but that does not work at all. Do you guys have any idea what I might be doing wrong? My Event Listener Code is attached:

```
var stopButtonEl = document.getElementById("StopButton");
stopButtonEl.addEventListener("click",clearTDLoop);
```

Sry for the prior confusion, where my code example stated "StartButton" as the button ID, I copied the wrong ID, the problem persists..

Comment: different ids, stop button and start button

Comment: See fiddle for amendment http://jsfiddle.net/xfFMk/282/

Comment: @seulberg1 could you please provide some fiddle?

Comment: Just remove the "El" from... var stopButtonEl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set an example code for you, please check it:

```js
var tdLoop;
var counter = 0;

var startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
startButton.addEventListener('click', startTDLoop, false);

var stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', clearTDLoop, false);

var result = document.getElementById('result');

function startTDLoop() {
  tdLoop = setInterval(updateValue, 1000);
}

function updateValue() {
  counter++;
  result.innerHTML = counter;
}

function clearTDLoop() {
  counter = 0;
  clearTimeout(tdLoop);
}
```

```css
#result {
  padding: 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class ="anhalteButton" id="startButton" value="Start"/>
<input type="button" class ="anhalteButton" id="stopButton" value="Stop"/>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I copied parts of your solution and somehow it works;) I'm afraid I am too bad a programmer to tell you why, but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @seulberg1 i'm happy that your problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the wrong ID for your event listener:

```
var startButtonEl = document.getElementById("StartButton");
startButtonEl.addEventListener("click",clearTDLoop);
```

Should be:

```
var stopButtonEl = document.getElementById("StopButton");
stopButtonEl.addEventListener("click",clearTDLoop);
```

Comment: sry, copied the wrong line of code, I call the StopButton